# Jax rs optional header param

Tags: jax-rs

I am using dropwizard and jax rs to build my simple webapp. I read that all the query params specified in my method definition are optional and so are the HeaderParams. But here is where I am facing problem.

When I skip passing any query param, still the request is routed to the appropriate method. But when I skip passing header param, my request is not even routed to that method. Kindly help.

Example)

```
@GET
@Path(/sample)
Public Response getSample(@HeaderParam("header") final String header,
     @QueryParam("query") final String query) {
}
```

In this sample, if I call this method with "header", this method gets invoked irrespective of whether I pass "query" param or not. At the same time, if I don't pass the "header", this method is not even getting invoked.

Also even if I give curl -H "header:" "http://localhost/sample?query=dummy" the request is not getting routed. I have to necessarily give a value for my header. Kindly help.

Note: I wrote down simplified representation of my code. Internally I am using dropwizard and swagger.

Thanks,
Sriram

Comment: Have you already tried to define a default value like `@DefaultValue("")` for header which you check in the implementation for anything other than an empty string? By not invoked, do you mean an other method is invoked? or do you get back a 404 failure?

Comment: Thanks Roman for getting back. When I keep break point inside my method, the control is not coming inside and Jersey container is throwing Resource not found error. With respect to the String typed header, I probably over simplified it. I am using a custom object which extends io.dropwizard.jersey.params.LongParam for my header param. Because of this I am not able to set a default value in @ DefaultParam annotation, as I cannot use @ DefaultParam(new MyObject()) because @DefaultParam expects a constant to be passed and not a dynamic object.

Comment: Can you try and replace the `LongParam` type with a simple `String` type for the header and see if the error remains? According to [the user-guide](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#d0e2192) if a value can't be parsed into an other type a 404 error will be returned. Maybe dropwizzard tries to convert `null` into `LongParam` which it fails for some reason and therefore throws a failure.

Comment: Oh nice! Good suggestion. Will try it out.